# SegFault in read function for serial device

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, serial-port

I'm attempting to interface with a measurement device through serial. I have already created one successful program that works and does what I want, but it doesn't have live user input.
My problem comes from a program I'm creating where I want to make a live serial terminal to interact with the device. In this program I have the user type the commands to the machine and for some commands the machine has to return a 1 or 0. This is where the problem comes. In the live environment, when I read a 1 after a command I get a segfault.

This is the segment that deals with commands that require the machine to send a 1 or 0.

```
buf = malloc(1);
if (buf == NULL)
{
    perror("memory error");
    goto fail;
}
...
if (write == 0)
{
      for (i = 0; i < read_com.num; i++)
      {
            if (strcmp(buff, read_com.check[i]) == 0)
            {
                ret = write_port(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
                if (ret < 0)
                    goto fail;
                ret = read_port(fd, buf, 1);
                if (ret < 0)
                    goto fail;
                printf("Read success");
                write = 1;
                break;
            }
      }
}
```

This is the read port function where the segfault is occurring

```
int read_port(int fd, char *buf, const size_t size)
{
    ssize_t r;
    size_t received;
    received = 0;
    while (received < size)
    {
        r = read(fd, buf + received, size - received);
        if (r < 0)
        {
            perror("failed to read from port");
            return -1;
        }
        if (r == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        received += r;
    }
    return received;
}
```

All code below:

live.c:

```
#include "GPIB_prof.h"
#include "serial.h"
#include "commands.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const struct com read_com = {3, {"OPC?;PRES;\r", "OPC?;WAIT;\r", "CORRON;\r"}};
const struct com numc = {3, {"STAR", "STOP", "POIN"}};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    int ret;
    char *buff;
    char *buf;
    int i;
    bool write = 0;
    int fin = 0;
    char *numb;
    char *rem;
    int star;
    int stop;
    int poin;
    char *dat;
    int fc = 0;
    char *file;
    FILE *temp;
    FILE *f;

    rem = malloc(256);
    if (rem == NULL)
    {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }
    numb = malloc(4);
    if (numb == NULL)
    {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }
    buff = malloc(256);
    if (buff == NULL)
    {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }
    buf = malloc(1);
    if (buf == NULL)
    {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }
    file = malloc(5);
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [serial device] [baud rate]", argv[0]);
        goto fail;
    }

    fd = open_port(argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
    if (fd < 0)
        goto fail;

    ret = GPIB_conf(fd, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;

    while (fin == 0)
    {
        write = 0;
        scanf("%s", buff);
        strcat(buff, "\r");
        //if (ret<0) goto fail;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(buff); i++)
        {
            if (i < 4)
            {
                numb[i] = buff[i];
            }
            else
            {
                rem[i - 4] = buff[i];
            }
        }
        if (strcmp(numb, "OUTP") == 0)
        {
            ret = write_port(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
            if (ret < 0)
                goto fail;
            write = 1;
            ret = read_port(fd, dat, 50 * poin);
            if (ret < 0)
                goto fail;
            else
                goto data;
        }
        if (write == 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < read_com.num; i++)
            {
                if (strcmp(buff, read_com.check[i]) == 0)
                {
                    ret = write_port(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
                    if (ret < 0)
                        goto fail;
                    ret = read_port(fd, buf, 1);
                    if (ret < 0)
                        goto fail;
                    printf("Read success");
                    write = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (write == 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < numc.num; i++)
            {
                if (strcmp(numb, numc.check[i]) == 0)
                {
                    ret = write_port(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
                    if (ret < 0)
                        goto fail;
                    write = 1;
                    if (strcmp(numb, "STAR") == 0)
                    {
                        star = atoi(rem);
                    }
                    else if (strcmp(numb, "STOP") == 0)
                    {
                        stop = atoi(rem);
                    }
                    else if (strcmp(numb, "POIN") == 0)
                    {
                        poin = atoi(rem);
                        dat = malloc(50 * poin);
                        if (dat == NULL)
                        {
                            perror("memory error");
                            goto fail;
                        }
                        fc++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (write == 0)
            {
                ret = write_port(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
                if (ret < 0)
                    goto fail;
                write = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Start freq: %d\nStop freq: %d\n", star, stop);

    free(rem);
    free(numb);
    free(buff);
    free(buf);
    free(file);
    free(dat);
    return 0;
data:
    ret = sprintf(file, "data%d", fc);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;
    temp = fopen(file, "w+");
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        perror("failed to open file");
        fclose(temp);
        goto fail;
    }
    fclose(temp);
    ret = remove(file);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        perror("failed to remove file");
        goto fail;
    }
    f = fopen(file, "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("failed to open file");
        fclose(f);
        goto fail;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (50 * poin); i++)
    {
        ret = fprintf(f, "%c", dat[i]);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fclose(f);
            goto fail;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    fin++;

fail:
    free(rem);
    free(numb);
    free(buff);
    free(buf);
    free(file);
    free(dat);
    return -1;
}
```

serial.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <termios.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    
    #include "serial.h"
    #include "GPIB_prof.h"
    
    struct termios options;
    
    int open_port(const char *dev, uint32_t baud)
    {
        int fd;
        int ret;
        char *baud_f;
        struct termios opt;
    
        baud_f = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
        if (baud_f == NULL)
        {
            perror("memory error");
            goto fail;
        }
    
        fd = open(dev, O_RDWR, 0777);
        if (fd < 0)
        {
            perror(dev);
            goto fail;
        }
        ret = tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
        if (ret)
        {
            perror("tcgetattr failed");
            goto fail;
        }
    
        opt.c_cflag = (opt.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;
        opt.c_cflag &= ~IGNBRK;
        opt.c_lflag = 0;
        opt.c_oflag = 0;
    
        opt.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;
        opt.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    
        opt.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
        opt.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
        opt.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
        opt.c_cflag |= 0;
        opt.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    
        ret = sprintf(baud_f, "B%d", baud);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            perror("memory error");
            goto fail;
        }
        baud = (uintptr_t)baud_f;
        cfsetospeed(&opt, baud);
        cfsetispeed(&opt, baud);
    
        ret = tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &opt);
        if (ret)
        {
            perror("tcsetarre failed");
            goto fail;
        }
    
        free(baud_f);
        return fd;
    
    fail:
        free(baud_f);
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }
    
    int read_port(int fd, char *buf, const size_t size)
    {
        ssize_t r;
        size_t received;
        received = 0;
        while (received < size)
        {
            r = read(fd, buf + received, size - received);
            if (r < 0)
            {
                perror("failed to read from port");
                return -1;
            }
            if (r == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            received += r;
        }
        return received;
    }
    
    int write_port(int fd, const char *buf, const size_t size)
    {
        ssize_t res;
        res = write(fd, buf, size);
        if (res != (ssize_t)size)
        {
            perror("failed to write to port");
            return -1;
        }
        usleep(size * 100);
        return 0;
    }
    
    int GPIB_conf(int fd, int profile)
    {
        int ret;
    
        switch (profile)
        {
        case 0:
            ret = def(fd);
            if (ret < 0)
                goto fail;
        }
        return 0;
    
    fail:
        return -1;
    }
```

serial.h

```
#ifndef _SERIAL_H_
#define _SERIAL_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "GPIB_prof.h"

int open_port (const char *dev, uint32_t baud);
int read_port (int fd, char *buf, size_t size);
int write_port (int fd, const char *buf, size_t size);
int GPIB_conf (int fd, int profile);

#endif
```

commands.h:

```
#ifndef _COMMANDS_H_
#define _COMMANDS_H_

struct com
{
    const int num;
    const char *check[]; 
};

#endif
```

GPIB_prof.c:

```
#include "GPIB_prof.h"
#include "serial.h"

int def(int fd)
{
    int ret;

    ret = write_port(fd, "++mode 1\r", 9);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;
    ret = write_port(fd, "++addr 16\r", 10);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;
    ret = write_port(fd, "++eoi 0\r", 8);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;
    ret = write_port(fd, "++eot_enable 1\r", 15);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;
    ret = write_port(fd, "++eot_char 13\r", 14);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;
    ret = write_port(fd, "++ifc\r", 6);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;
    ret = write_port(fd, "++auto 1\r", 9);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;

    return 0;
fail:
    return -1;
}
```

GPIB_prof.h:

```
#ifndef _PROFILE_H_
#define _PROFILE_H_

int def(int fd);

#endif
```

Comment: You do `malloc(1)` for `buf` [which allocates only _one_ byte--probably too short]. But you also have `buff`. Is `buff` different from `buf` or is this a typo? You're using _both_ symbols in the code, so please clarify.

Comment: I do use buff as well, they are different. I'll admit the naming is quite poor. I know that 1 byte isn't too short as well because I do the same thing in my other program. I am also only attempting to read 1 byte from the serial device.

Comment: You should post more code. In particular, showing more of the `buff` related definitions and allocations. Based on what you just said in your comment, it's _not_ possible for `read_port` to segfault [assuming `fd` is valid]. So, the issue has to be elsewhere. If you've got UB (undefined behavior) you might be trashing the pointer that is passed to `read_port`. I think 300 lines is small enough to post the code. Add it at the bottom of the question in a separate code block.

Comment: How do you know where the segfault occurs? Have you run the code under `gdb` and done a backtrace? Without that [or debug `printf` statements], it's difficult to pin things down. Also, what is the exact data that causes the issue. Is it user input or what you get from the serial port?

Comment: I haven't done a proper backtrace but I know that gdb says its from the read() function. That is the read function from unistd.h. The exact data is the device sending a 1 after the "OPC?;PRES;\r" command is sent. The "OPC?;" says send a 1 if the next command returns sucess and "PRES;" tells the machine to run preset. I have confirmed that the machine does this when the commands are sent through this live program.

Comment: `gdb` can show you the args passed to `read`. Are they valid/sensible? In particular the buffer pointer and the length [as well]?

Comment: Yeah the args are valid, they're the buf and size 1 that I send in the original code snippet. Surely there's nothing wrong with sending a buf of size 1 with the length as 1. Also I know that my file descriptor is valid because the machine correctly receives my write request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Caveat:* This may not be a total solution as there are *many* compiler warnings for possibly uninitialized variables, etc.

Note that I'd rename some variables. You have a global called `read`. That tends to conflict with the standard `read` function. (i.e.) don't define functions/variables that conflict with standard functions/variables: caveat emptor.

---

Here is the compiler output I get for (e.g.) `cc -o orig orig.c -Wall -Wextra -O2`.

Notably, a number of *pointer* variables may have uninitialized values. This really should be restructured and the warnings fixed as the code is fragile and the compiler is pointing out things that could easily explain your runtime error(s).

```
orig.c: In function ‘GPIB_conf’:
orig.c:136:15: warning: unused parameter ‘fd’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 GPIB_conf(int fd, int profile)
           ~~~~^~
orig.c: In function ‘main’:
orig.c:217:17: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   for (i = 0; i < strlen(buff); i++) {
                 ^
orig.c:325:5: warning: increment of a boolean expression [-Wbool-operation]
  fin++;
     ^~
orig.c: In function ‘open_port’:
orig.c:96:2: warning: ‘fd’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  close(fd);
  ^~~~~~~~~
orig.c: In function ‘main’:
orig.c:295:27: warning: ‘%d’ directive writing between 1 and 10 bytes into a region of size 1 [-Wformat-overflow=]
  ret = sprintf(file, "data%d", fc);
                           ^~
orig.c:295:22: note: directive argument in the range [0, 2147483647]
  ret = sprintf(file, "data%d", fc);
                      ^~~~~~~~
orig.c:295:8: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 6 and 15 bytes into a destination of size 5
  ret = sprintf(file, "data%d", fc);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
orig.c:332:2: warning: ‘file’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  free(file);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
orig.c:333:2: warning: ‘dat’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  free(dat);
  ^~~~~~~~~
orig.c:329:2: warning: ‘numb’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  free(numb);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
orig.c:331:2: warning: ‘buf’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  free(buf);
  ^~~~~~~~~
orig.c:330:2: warning: ‘buff’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  free(buff);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
orig.c:230:32: warning: ‘poin’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    ret = read_port(fd, dat, 50 * poin);
                             ~~~^~~~~~
```

---

I had to refactor/nop some of the code to get it to compile without the full definitions in the [missing] `.h` files. However, these hacks do *not* account for the warnings above.

```
#include "GPIB_prof.h"
#include "serial.h"
#include "commands.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define def(_fd) \
    0

struct com {
    int num;
    char *check[3];
};

const struct com read_com = { 3, {"OPC?;PRES;\r", "OPC?;WAIT;\r", "CORRON;\r"} };
const struct com numc = { 3, {"STAR", "STOP", "POIN"} };

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "serial.h"
#include "GPIB_prof.h"

struct termios options;

int
open_port(const char *dev, uint32_t baud)
{
    int fd;
    int ret;
    char *baud_f;
    struct termios opt;

    baud_f = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
    if (baud_f == NULL) {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }

    fd = open(dev, O_RDWR, 0777);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror(dev);
        goto fail;
    }
    ret = tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
    if (ret) {
        perror("tcgetattr failed");
        goto fail;
    }

    opt.c_cflag = (opt.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;
    opt.c_cflag &= ~IGNBRK;
    opt.c_lflag = 0;
    opt.c_oflag = 0;

    opt.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;
    opt.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;

    opt.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    opt.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    opt.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
    opt.c_cflag |= 0;
    opt.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;

    ret = sprintf(baud_f, "B%d", baud);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }
    baud = (uintptr_t) baud_f;
    cfsetospeed(&opt, baud);
    cfsetispeed(&opt, baud);

    ret = tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &opt);
    if (ret) {
        perror("tcsetarre failed");
        goto fail;
    }

    free(baud_f);
    return fd;

  fail:
    free(baud_f);
    close(fd);
    return -1;
}

int
read_port(int fd, char *buf, const size_t size)
{
    ssize_t r;
    size_t received;

    received = 0;
    while (received < size) {
        r = read(fd, buf + received, size - received);
        if (r < 0) {
            perror("failed to read from port");
            return -1;
        }
        if (r == 0) {
            break;
        }
        received += r;
    }
    return received;
}

int
write_port(int fd, const char *buf, const size_t size)
{
    ssize_t res;

    res = write(fd, buf, size);
    if (res != (ssize_t) size) {
        perror("failed to write to port");
        return -1;
    }
    usleep(size * 100);
    return 0;
}

int
GPIB_conf(int fd, int profile)
{
    int ret;

    switch (profile) {
    case 0:
        ret = def(fd);
        if (ret < 0)
            goto fail;
    }
    return 0;

  fail:
    return -1;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    int ret;
    char *buff;
    char *buf;
    int i;
    bool write = 0;
    bool fin = 0;
    char *numb;
    char *rem;
    int star;
    int stop;
    int poin;
    char *dat;
    int fc = 0;
    char *file;
    FILE *temp;
    FILE *f;

    rem = malloc(256);
    if (rem == NULL) {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }
    numb = malloc(4);
    if (numb == NULL) {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }
    buff = malloc(256);
    if (buff == NULL) {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }
    buf = malloc(1);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }
    file = malloc(5);
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s [serial device] [baud rate]", argv[0]);
        goto fail;
    }

    fd = open_port(argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
    if (fd < 0)
        goto fail;

    ret = GPIB_conf(fd, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;

    while (fin == 0) {
        write = 0;
        scanf("%s", buff);
        strcat(buff, "\r");
        // if (ret<0) goto fail;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(buff); i++) {
            if (i < 4) {
                numb[i] = buff[i];
            }
            else {
                rem[i - 4] = buff[i];
            }
        }
        if (strcmp(numb, "OUTP") == 0) {
            ret = write_port(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
            if (ret < 0)
                goto fail;
            write = 1;
            ret = read_port(fd, dat, 50 * poin);
            if (ret < 0)
                goto fail;
            else
                goto data;
        }
        if (write == 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < read_com.num; i++) {
                if (strcmp(buff, read_com.check[i]) == 0) {
                    ret = write_port(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
                    if (ret < 0)
                        goto fail;
                    ret = read_port(fd, buf, 1);
                    if (ret < 0)
                        goto fail;
                    printf("Read success");
                    write = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (write == 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < numc.num; i++) {
                if (strcmp(numb, numc.check[i]) == 0) {
                    ret = write_port(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
                    if (ret < 0)
                        goto fail;
                    write = 1;
                    if (strcmp(numb, "STAR") == 0) {
                        star = atoi(rem);
                    }
                    else if (strcmp(numb, "STOP") == 0) {
                        stop = atoi(rem);
                    }
                    else if (strcmp(numb, "POIN") == 0) {
                        poin = atoi(rem);
                        dat = malloc(50 * poin);
                        if (dat == NULL) {
                            perror("memory error");
                            goto fail;
                        }
                        fc++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (write == 0) {
                ret = write_port(fd, buff, strlen(buff));
                if (ret < 0)
                    goto fail;
                write = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Start freq: %d\nStop freq: %d\n", star, stop);

    free(rem);
    free(numb);
    free(buff);
    free(buf);
    free(file);
    free(dat);
    return 0;
  data:
    ret = sprintf(file, "data%d", fc);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;
    temp = fopen(file, "w+");
    if (temp == NULL) {
        perror("failed to open file");
        fclose(temp);
        goto fail;
    }
    fclose(temp);
    ret = remove(file);
    if (ret != 0) {
        perror("failed to remove file");
        goto fail;
    }
    f = fopen(file, "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("failed to open file");
        fclose(f);
        goto fail;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (50 * poin); i++) {
        ret = fprintf(f, "%c", dat[i]);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fclose(f);
            goto fail;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    fin++;

  fail:
    free(rem);
    free(numb);
    free(buff);
    free(buf);
    free(file);
    free(dat);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I updated my post to include actually all the code. Sorry about that, completely forgot about the other headers. This should fix the compile errors you're getting, as I get none when I compile this. I have a feeling that changing the name of the read struct won't change the outcome, but it could. I can't test this until monday, though I suspect when I try a gdb backtrace the problem will reveal itself.